# jQuery .load() and cache image conflict

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, load, image

By using the custom function (loadContent) below I have run into a snag. If I visit the work page (URL below) it waits to load images then hides the overlay (which is great!). If I leave the work page (visit a project) and then revisit the work page later it no longer works. Firebug shows on the second page visit everything is loaded properly but the overlay never goes away. Something appears to be hanging prior to the hideOverlay(); function gets executed if the loadContent(); function has been previously ran for that respected page.

The current WIP can be found at  [edit: URL has been removed]

**My load Function**

```
function loadContent(link) {
 var loadUrl = $(link).attr("href");
 showOverlay(function () {
    $('#holder').load(loadUrl, function () {
        var imgcount = $('#holder img').length;
        $('#holder img').load(function () {
            imgcount--; if (imgcount == 0) {
                $('#content').scrollTop(0);
                hideOverlay();
            };
         });
      })
  });
}
```

**The overlay Functions**

```
function showOverlay(callback) {
   $('html').addClass('overlay-visible');
   $('#overlay').fadeIn(500, callback);
};


function hideOverlay(callback) {
  $('html').removeClass('overlay-visible');
  $('#overlay').delay(100).fadeOut(500, callback);
};
```

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use image preloading rather than relying on the images existing in the dom, if they are already cached they may trigger the load event before you bind to it.

```
$('#holder').load(loadUrl, function () {

    var defArr = $("#holder img").map(function(){
        var def = $.Deferred();
        var img = new Image();
        // bind to load event before setting src, very important!
        $(img).load(def.resolve);
        img.src = this.src;
        return def.promise();
    });

    $.when.apply($,defArr).done(function(){
        // hide overlay
    });

});
```

Comment: Kevin, thanks for taking the time to help. Can you please explain to me the 'bind to load event before setting src, very important'? On a scale of 1-10, I am probably a 5 on jQuery and you;ve used a few things that are new to me. Quite honestly, this is first time I've seen the deferred object. I'm a print guy moving to digital :/

Comment: Basically what happens is the load event gets triggered as soon as the image is appended to the dom, which is BEFORE you're binding your load event. In my code, i'm binding the load event to a new image element before giving that image element a src. Once I give it a src, it will immediately trigger the load event if the image is cached.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I misinterpreted. I thought you were suggesting I do something in order to bind to load event. Many thanks!